# Staging Error when deploying node.js app to IBM Bluemix

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I am trying to deploy a Node.js application to Bluemix. In the logs the app downloads all the node modules, compiles, and starts to build. It then errors out with an error: **FAILED: Error restarting application: StagingError**. There is no other information. I have tried to set `CF_Trace = true`. When I checked the logs using `cf logs <appname> --recent`, I get the following trace:

```
[STG/0]      OUT        [19:47:20] Finished 'bower' after 10 s
[STG/0]      OUT        [19:47:20] Starting 'fonts'...
[STG/0]      OUT        [19:47:20] fonts all files 2.03 MB
[STG/0]      OUT        [19:47:20] Finished 'fonts' after 68 ms
[STG/0]      OUT        [19:47:20] Starting 'compile'...
[STG/0]      OUT        [19:47:20] Finished 'compile' after 33 μs
[STG/0]      OUT        [19:47:20] Starting 'build'...
[STG/0]      ERR 
[API/0]      ERR encountered error: Staging error: failed to stage application:
ERR Script exited with status 255
```

Has anyone encountered this error when deploying a node.js app to Bluemix before?

Comment: Are you using any environment variables / have you looked at this? https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/10134/staging-error-cannot-get-instances-since-staging-failed.html

Comment: I just deployed an app successfully via the Bluemix UI.  Are you using DevOp Services?

Comment: I am using the cf command line tool to deploy. I think the issue was I haven't completely removed dependency on some services we are no longer using. When I added the services back on Bluemix, it was able to deploy.